# Question of the Week #46

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post #46 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the Super User blog. Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any questions that you feel is of worth and the reason why. Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake. We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the Super User Contest. If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Answer (score 5):

> ## [How does Windows detect battery issues?](https://superuser.com/questions/619930/how-does-windows-detect-battery-issues)
>
> I have a laptop that's a little over 5 years old, and I've never changed the battery, so I believe Windows 7 when it tells me "there is a problem with your battery", and to consider replacing it.
>
> My question is: how does it detect a dodgy battery? Does the battery not have the same voltage that it used to?

I think this is an interesting question, and could form the basis for a blog post with some more detail about how battery technology works and why batteries degrade over time, or perhaps more detail about ACPI and how it works.

Comment: It is too vague; as different versions of Windows act detect & react differently.

Comment: So then have different sections of the blog talking about different versions of windows. Simple thinking @tomByrer

Comment: Fair enough @OnkaPlonka
Perhaps there should be different sections for different battery tech as well?

Comment: Great Idea! P.S. Sorry if the 'Simple Thinking' sounded a bit like I has having a go at you as this was not the intention.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Windows 8.1 comes with SQL Server and Visual C++?
>
> My friend got a new Windows 8.1 laptop. I am helping her cleanup
>   things that came "free" from HP (games, etc).
>
> In the list of programs installed, I see "Microsoft SQL Server 2005
>   Compact Edition" and 9 versions of "Microsoft Visual C++
>   Redistributable" (ranging from 2005 to 2010).
>
> She is no developer and never installed those. What are they doing
>   here? Is it safe to uninstall?

Just a good question: Very clear, easy to get to the point.

Comment: You're about a year too late...